# Collision resolution with rectangles in C++

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

I am working on a 3D maze game where the labyrinth itself is generated automatically and randomly each time I run the program. So basically the walls are always somewhere else. (don't mind the "3D", it basically works like 2D, because there's nothing to do with the vertical axis)

*My question/problem:* Basically I don't know how to make it impossible to go through the walls. It works successfully as long as I don't press a key for too long time and then immediately change to the opposite direction. So, like I press button "UP" for a while against a wall, then I press "DOWN" and it detects that it actually collides with the wall, so it starts to add some values to the position, so basically it goes thru with the opposite key! Hope you got it!

(I tried to modify my code like in the function IsCollide, I don't add or substract values just make the position remain the same but then it all stucks once it collides..)

I successfully detected collision between walls and the character (which is a cube actually) with the following function:

```
bool IsCollide(Cube character, std::vector<Cube> maze)
{
    bool collided = false;
    for (auto i : maze)
        if (i.position.z < character.position.z + character.size.z &&
            i.position.z + i.size.z > character.position.z &&
            i.position.x < character.position.x + character.size.x &&
            i.size.x + i.position.x > character.position.x)
        {
            collided = true;
            return collided;
        } return collided;
}
```

Now my problem is that I am not able to properly use this with the keyboard input. I show you my code, where I am so far.

```
static void MoveCharacter(Cube& character, Keyboard keyboard, std::vector<Cube> maze)
{
        if (keyboard.getKey(GLFW_KEY_UP))
        {
            if ((character.position.x >= MazeHeight - 1.0f)) //top of the maze, don't let it go out
            {
               character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (IsCollide(character, maze)) //it shall go a bit backwards, if it collides
            {
               character.position -= glm::vec3(0.01, 0, 0);
            }
            else character.position += glm::vec3(0.01, 0, 0); //now you can go
        }
        if (keyboard.getKey(GLFW_KEY_DOWN))
        {
            if ((character.position.x <= 0.0f))
            {
                character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (IsCollide(character, maze))
            {
               character.position += glm::vec3(0.01, 0, 0);
            }
            else character.position -= glm::vec3(0.01, 0, 0);

        }
        if (keyboard.getKey(GLFW_KEY_RIGHT))
        {
            if (character.position.z >= MazeWidth - 1.0f)
            {
                character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (IsCollide(character, maze))
            {
                character.position -= glm::vec3(0, 0, 0.01);
            }
            else character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0.01);

        }
        if (keyboard.getKey(GLFW_KEY_LEFT))
        {
            if ((character.position.z <= 0.0f))
            {
                character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (IsCollide(character, maze))
            {
                character.position += glm::vec3(0, 0, 0.01);
            }
            else character.position -= glm::vec3(0, 0, 0.01);
        }
        if (character.position.x >= MazeHeight - 1.0f && character.position.z >= MazeWidth - 1.0f)
        {
            std::cout << "YOU WIN" << std::endl;
            //reached the goal
        }

}
```

Hope you can help me, I would appreciate it a lot! Thank you guys!

Comment: If the collision detection is working, what about always having the characters previous position saved - and if it hits a wall, set it back to its previous position. It's perhaps not the most elegant way but it should work without having to change any of the other logic.

Comment: This is what I thought should have worked but since this function is called in each key handling part, it simply does not move anymore - as i mentioned - once it collides with a wall.

Comment: If so, there's some other problem. If you don't have anything else than detecting that it hits and then setting it back to the previous position (without saving the illegal position as the previous position of course) it should just work. Time for debugging it seems :-)